# Explanation of a output of a C program involving fork()

Tags: c, fork

Running this program is printing "forked!" 7 times. Can someone explain how "forked!" is being printed 7 times?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(){

  fork() && fork() || fork() && fork();

  printf("forked!\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of 1000 other questions...it's due to buffering, unless your question is more specific.

Comment: How many times did you expect it to print?

Comment: Try writing out the boolean expression as nested if-then-elses, then draw the recursion tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There're several concepts being used here, first one is knowing what `fork` does and what it returns in certain circumstances. Shortly, when it gets called, it creates a duplicate process of the caller and returns `0` (`false` for logical expressions) in child process and non-zero (`true` for logical expressions) for parent process.
Actually, it could return a negative (non-zero) value in case of an error, but here we assume that it always succeeds.

The second concept is short-circuit computation of logical expressions, such as `&&` and `||`, specifically, `0 && fork()` will *not* call `fork()`, because if the first operand is `false` (zero), then there's no need to compute the second one. Similarly, `1 || fork()` will not call `fork()` neither.

Also note that in child processes the computation of the expression continues at the same point as in the parent process.

Also, note that the expression is computed in the following order due to precedence:

```
(fork() && fork()) || (fork() && fork())
```

These observations should lead you to the correct answer.

Consider the simplified example of `fork() && fork()`

```
   fork()        
  /     \
false   true && fork()
                /   \
             false  true
```

So here we have three processes created, two of which return `false` as the result and one returning `true`. Then for `||` we have all the processes returning `false` trying to run the same statement again, so we have `2 * 3 + 1 = 7` as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike I stated in my comment, this is not about buffering.   The process forks.  The parent executes the 2nd fork, while the child short circuits the second and executes the 3rd.  The first grandchild evaluates the first `&&` as false and executes the 3rd fork.  That spawns 2 processes, one of which evaluates the 4th fork.  Meanwhile (or before, or after...there's a race condition!), the other child has become 3 processes while evaluating the RHS of the `||`.  In all, 7 processes end up running.  Draw a tree.

To simplify the calculation, consider:

```
int f( void )
{
  int k; 
  k = fork();
  printf( "%d\n", (int) getpid());
  fflush( stdout );
  return k;
}

int main( void ) { f() && f() || f() && f(); return 0; }
```

Comment: Just for clarification: fork returns 0(false) for the child and the PID(true) of the child for the parent